# How can the certificates inside a Corda network be signed by Certificate Authority?

Tags: corda

How can the certificates inside a Corda network be signed by Certificate Authority? Is there a defined process for managing the certificates for each Node and participants in Corda network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To join a Corda network a Node needs to obtain a certificate from the Identity Manager of the network they want to connect to. It is described in the [documentation](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.8/network/joining-a-compatibility-zone.html) of Corda Enterprise:

> To connect to a compatibility zone you need to register with its
> certificate signing authority (or doorman) by **submitting a certificate
> signing request (CSR) to obtain a valid identity** for the zone. This
> process is only necessary when the node connects to the network for
> the first time, or when the certificate expires. You could do this out
> of band, for instance via email or a web form, but there’s also a
> simple request/response utility built into the node.
>
> Before using this utility, **you must first have received the trust
> store file containing the root certificate from the zone operator**. For
> high security zones, this might be delivered physically.

So, first the node operator needs to get in touch with the network operator offline and provide its X.509 information. The network operator will provide the node with:

> - `truststore.jks`, the network/zone operator’s root certificate in keystore with a locally configurable password as protection against
>   certain attacks

At this point the node can then use the node utilities to make a CSR (Certificate Signing Request) to the Identity Manager to obtain the node certificate and receive the following:

> - `nodekeystore.jks`, which stores the node’s identity key pairs and certificates

Note that this can be also provided directly by the network operatort, I guess it depends on their policy. It is also described in the [documentation](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.8/network/permissioning.html#key-pair-and-certificate-formats).

The node can also create its own `sslkeystore.jks`,

> which stores the node’s TLS key pair and certificate

that can be used, for example, to connect an external RPC client to the node.

The node certificate expires and can be revoked by the Identity Manager, so in that case it needs to make other specific request to obtain a new certificate.

Further readings:

- https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.8/network/permissioning.html
- https://docs.corda.net/docs/cenm/1.5/pki-guide.html#certificate-hierarchy-guide

Comment: In the case of certificate expiry, is there an automated process to perform key rotation? Once the keys are renewed, what happens to the previous transactions that were signed using the previous key? Are those transactions still resolvable to the node / party? 

Does the network keep the history of certificates against a node / part?

Comment: Corda Enterprise provide tools, but it depends on how the network is organized and the cordapps architected. https://docs.corda.net/docs/cenm/1.5/tools-index.html#node-certificate-rotation-tool .